# When we comment that translation requests are against the rules, should we not provide any translation?

Tags: discussion

To me, it seems we're incentivising bad behaviour if we respond to translation requests with comments that they are against the rules, but provide a translation anyway.

Should we avoid providing translations so that we don't look like we're not enforcing this rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My personal opinion is that giving a translation in the comments on first posts is OK. We do communicate the rules of our community (simple translation requests are off-topic), but also communicate that we're willing to help. I think this is more important than a strict rule against such comments.

(Of course from time to time there are users, who try to use take advantage of this and repeatedly post translation requests, hoping for a response in the comments. But I don't think it happens that often, and the community quickly notices that they're deliberately ignoring the rules and most people become quickly less willing to help.)

Comment: Fair enough, I agree. Unless there are repeated abuses of this from the same posters, I guess the directive to be helpful is probably more important.

Comment: Yeah, many new users who make translation requests react quite negatively to neutrally phrased refusals that don't include a translation. I assume it's because they thought it was obvious that it would be an allowed question type and feel a bit defensive to the idea that they "broke a rule." Including the translation softens it quite a bit, and as noted, it doesn't usually end up being a repeat thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this many times and I have to admit I never actually checked for repeat offenders when I probably should've. I agree with Earthliŋ that giving newcomers the benefit of the doubt is the way to go, not only to cultivate a welcoming community but also because the help center guidelines for asking good, on-topic questions is not obviously accessible from the JLSE homepage or even from the *Ask a public question* page.

Sure, there's a *Helpful links* section in the sidebar, but on my laptop screen it barely shows up in the bottom right corner of the monitor so it's easy to miss (see image).

[image]

As a language Stack Exchange, it's not unreasonable to think that newcomers believe this could be a place for translations. That combined with the reduced visibility of this website's guidelines makes it unlikely that newcomers will actually notice the *off-topic/no translations* agreement on JLSE.

Moreover, rather than telling unaware newcomers that they should go to another platform and go through the hassle of potentially making yet another account simply to translate a Japanese image or birthday message, I think giving the translation in a comment is a negligible effort compared to the inconvenience put on the new user otherwise.